# change 1column template

Tags: template, custom

I hope I can ask this question correctly.

I am attempting to edit the "1column.phtml" file so that the "side bar left" appears as well.
I have pulled the code from "2columns.phtml" and it works , how ever the alignment is off.

How can I have the "left side bar" appear next to the products, i have a photo showing what I am aiming for.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Placing sidebar in 1 column is not possible instead you cna place a CMS block and adjust it to required position using `css`

Comment: OK ill try that and see how it goes,
What I am trying to do is have a slider on top and two columns (sidebar and products) on the bottom of that.
Hope That makes some sense ,

Ill try the CMS block and try my luck with that

Thank you !

Comment: there is no layout file as '2columns.phtml' in default magento installation. However there are two 2columns layout files 1. 2columns-left.phtml 2. 2columns-right.phtml. If you want your navigation on the right you can use 2columns-right.phtml layout file. If you want totally different structural blocks you can create your own layout file.

Comment: Why don't you try using the `2columns-left.phtml` layout file and then insert the slider between the `<header>` and the `<main container>`?

Comment: Nasir - Yea looks like Ill have to make my own layout file for a custom structural block. Thank you

ForMat- Ill try that and see if I can getting working Thank you

Comment: If you get this working, please consider moving the comments into an answer to properly close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you are not limited to the supplied 1column.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml etc. You can create your own templates for custom pages.

Just copy+paste the necessary XML from `layout/page.xml`. For example:

Copy:

```
<page_one_column translate="label">
   <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
   <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
      </action>
      <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
      <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
      <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>one_column</name></action>
    </reference>
</page_one_column>
```

Paste + modify...

```
<page_custom_columns translate="label">
   <label>My Custom Layout Page</label>
   <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>page/mycustomtemplate.phtml</template>
      </action>
      <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
      <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
      <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>custom_column</name></action>
    </reference>
</page_custom_columns>
```

You could then apply this template to just the category pages. You could even limit it to just a few categories using the Design tab in the Magento admin area when managing categories.